# checking is user is signed in mail application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

i need to know is there any way to check that the user has given an id in mail application so that i can notify the user before calling MFMailComposeViewController that you are not signed in or you have not given an email id in mail application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> canSendMail
> ```
>
> Returns a Boolean indicating whether
>   the current device is able to send
>   email.
>
> ```
> + (BOOL)canSendMail
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> YES if the device is configured for
>   sending email or NO if it is not.
>   Discussion
>
> You should call this method before
>   attempting to display the mail
>   composition interface. If it returns
>   NO, you must not display the mail
>   composition interface.

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
//do something
}
else
{
// cannot send mail
}
```

Comment: can we get email id from which he is login

Comment: The API doesn't expose that information publicly (for probably good reasons, such as preventing developers from harvesting iPhone users' email addresses).

You should probably go about asking for the user's email address and then saving it for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by below code

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil)
{
    // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
    if ([mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        [self displayComposerSheet];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *objAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Mail Account" message:@"Please create an account first for sending mail." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [objAlert show];
        [objAlert release];
    }
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *objAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Mail Account" message:@"Please create an account first for sending mail." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [objAlert show];
    [objAlert release];
}
```